# JavaFX Custom Control Can't move fxml in package --> FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, javafx, package, classnotfoundexception, fxml

I have created a new (Control) Class that extends of BorderPane. This class loads an FXML in the constructor.

In another fxml, I am using this Control this way . It works perfectly, however, as soon as I try to move MyController.fxml (and its class that extends BorderPane) in another package, I get a ClassNotFoundException even if I did correct the imports/includes.

Thanks

Edit :

Here is a screenshot for more details. As soon as I move TowerUI into the UI package, I get the exception (that you can also see on the screenshot)

URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYWGn.png

[image]

Edit 2 :

TowerUI.java : http://pastebin.com/MCuxEJVE

Comment: are both the pacakges in the same jar ? is it that you are moving the parent class to an internal package ?

Comment: Hi, please take a look to this screenshot, TowerUI is what I move. If I move it in the UI package, it makes an exception, otherwise it is fine.  http://i.imgur.com/eCP68A1.png

Comment: Can you add code for `TowerUI.java` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  Sure, Here you go :) http://pastebin.com/MCuxEJVE  Tried removing everything in the constructor and same exception.